# Bootstrap Grid Columns - HTML Labels causing incorrect layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I've got the following html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        @*@Html.LabelFor(s => s.BasicInfo.FirstName)*@<label>First Name:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.BasicInfo.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        @*@Html.LabelFor(s => s.BasicInfo.LastName)*@<label>Last Name:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.BasicInfo.LastName)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        @*@Html.LabelFor(s => s.BasicInfo.City)*@<label>City:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.BasicInfo.City)
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        @*@Html.LabelFor(s => s.BasicInfo.State)*@<label>State:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.BasicInfo.State)
    </div>
</div>
```

When I pull up the page in IE or Firefox, the "xs", "md", and "lg" sizes work fine, but the "sm" size's layout is incorrect.  If I remove the `<label>` tag from the html, all sizes work fine. Is this html/razor/css valid?  I've looked online for any issues with placing other html elements inside of a column, but I can't imagine there would be any issues. I tried to include some screenshots, but they were not showing up so I removed them.

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML rather than the above? Also I don't think you need to have the col-lg-3 classes as the col-md-3 will be used on larger screens if no large col is declared.

Comment: 6 x 4 is 24 and unless all col-sm-6 are the same height, the layout won't clear correctly. Also, col-xs-12 and col-lg-3 are not required.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and answers! I'm working on my solution now and will let you all know what I find and what works.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can remove `.col-xs-12` and `.col-lg-3` and still have the same layout.

Secondly, the code looks alright, but it would be nice to see the full generated code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm working on my solution now and will let you all know what I find. If I'm still stuck I will post the generated html.

Comment: I think that @Christina is right and the issue is that you have 24 columns in a row on sm-screen. And they are not cleared properly.